# Python : Detect Color Then Click Color

Tags: python, colors

I am trying to take a screen shot, check the screen shot for a certain color, if the color is found then click on it.

The problem I'm having is that the RGB values of the color has to be exact.

I was wondering if it was possible to convert the image to an image with very few colors.

I'm sorry for the clutter. I am not properly trained. I am just obsessed with coding now.

Thank you for taking the time to read this.

```
import os, sys
import Image, ImageGrab, ImageOps
import time, random
from random import randrange
import win32api, win32con
from numpy import *


# Globals
# ------------------

x_pad = 0
y_pad = 0


# Screen Grab Function
def screenGrab():
    b1 = (x_pad + 1,y_pad+1,x_pad+1921,y_pad+1081)
    im = ImageGrab.grab()
    ##im.save(os.getcwd() + '\\Snap__' + str(int(time.time())) +'.png', 'PNG')
    return im

## Grab Mouse Position
## MousePos = win32api.GetCursorPos()
## print MousePos

## Type in shell to grab RGB color
## im = screenGrab()
## im.getpixel(MousePos)

## Check Mouse Position for Black
## s = screenGrab()
## if s.getpixel(MousePos) <= (96, 96, 96):
    ##print "I see black."   

# Main 

x = 920
y = 465

# Color Check Then Stop/Click Loop

while True:

    s = screenGrab()
    s.convert("P", palette=Image.ADAPTIVE, colors=5)
    x = x + 10
    xy = (x, y)
    if s.getpixel(xy)== (255, 255, 255):
        break
    else:
        win32api.SetCursorPos((x, y))
        print x
        print y

        if x == 1250:
            x = 700
            y = y + 10
            if y == 985:
                break
```

How do I use "s.convert("P", palette=Image.ADAPTIVE, colors=5)" correctly so that I limit the range of colors to something like (0, 255, 0)?

Comment: Could you be more precise where is a problem and your question?

Comment: How do I use

"s.convert("P", palette=Image.ADAPTIVE, colors=5)"

correctly so that I limit the range of colors to something like (0, 255, 0)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of simplifying your color why don't you give range of RGB values when trying to find what color it is?

```
(range(200,220), range(200,220), range(200,220))
```

This would work around changing the RGB values of all the pixels.

Comment: I know this is not exactly what you might want, but it is a work-around

Comment: Thank you. That is pretty much what I was looking for. I can remove the s.convert line now right?

Comment: "if s.getpixel(xy)== (range(0, 255), range(0, 255), range(0, 255)):
        break"

That should make it break on any color right?

Bah, this is challenging. =(

Comment: You can remove the s.convert line, and yes, it would make it break on every possible color.

Comment: For some reason it's not breaking. The code just runs... =(

Comment: You need to say: `if s.getpixel(xy)[0] ==range(0,255) and s.getpixel(xy)[1] == range(0,255)`... Tell me if this doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. What does [0] and [1] do?

Comment: I tried it. It is not breaking on any color, including white.

Comment: Paste this into your code: `if s.getpixel(xy)[0] ==range(0,255) and s.getpixel(xy)[1] == range(0,255) and s.getpixel(xy)[2] == range(0,255): break`

Comment: Still not breaking. Maybe it's better I start from scratch with the range concept?

Comment: Yah, start from stratch. There are a couple things to note: first what does `s.getpixel(xy)` return? and second `range` gives a list of numbers between what numbers you give. Play around with those things and it will all work out.

Comment: s.getpixel(xy) gets the pixel color in xy coordinates off of a screenshot. Thanks for the help.